# Undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I have a variable: `@delivery_time`.

When i do this

```
o.delivery_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

It gives

```
undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass
```

And when i do this:

```
debug o.delivery_time
```

It gives:

```
--- 2000-01-01 11:00:00.000000000 Z  ...
```

Also, the output for:

```
o.delivery_time
```

is

```
2000-01-01 11:00:00 UTC
```

Here i want the value of time only i.e. 11:00. So tried srtftime but it is not working.

Can anybody help in this?

Comment: show the body of the method `delievery_time`.

Comment: @RubyLovely u mean this?: <%= f.time_select :delivery_time, {:default => 5.hours.from_now, :minute_step => 5, :ampm => true} %>, where delivery_time is of type 'time' in database.

Comment: try changing the 'time' type in the db to 'datetime'

Comment: @neon but delivery time is 'time' type. And in DB it stores time. But for print, it prints date as well.

Comment: In your comment below you say "for some fields delivery time is nil". Are you calling this in a loop, i.e. for different `o`'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did a trick :

```
 o.delivery_time.to_formatted_s(:time)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have same kind of issue and following code helps me to display hour and minutes for field "time".

```
 o.try(:delivery_time).try(:strftime, ("%H:%M"))
```

Answer (score 0):

typo: delievery_time vs delivery_time

**EDIT** Try this:

```
o.try(:delivery_time).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: what's the output for "o.delivery_time.class"

Comment: For some fields delivery time is nill. May be cause of that it is showing error.

Comment: the output of  "o.delivery_time.class" is Time. And on fields of Time output, it shows srtftime error

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `(:strftime,(" %m/%d/%Y %I:%M"))`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solves in this way:

```
o.delivery_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") unless o.delivery_time.nil?
```